# How to handle back button press in Custom View in android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, keylistener

```
 relativeLayout.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {                
                if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {               
                       do....something                   
                }
                return false;
            }
```

}

This code is  not working. When I press on backbutton, It doesn't shows any response. Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance ......

Comment: I mean hardware key event (Device back button). Is there any way to handle handle back button press in custom view

Comment: You might [need to delegate it to the custom view through its container, the container also being a custom view](https://github.com/Zhuinden/flow-sample/blob/1.0/src/main/java/com/example/flow/MainActivity.java#L134)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there, but this is exaclty what you need to do.

```
relativeLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
relativeLayout.requestFocus();
relativeLayout.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

         if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if(You have handled the back press in your View){ return true; }
                return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Athira, It shows an error 'Cannot resolve method in getView'

Comment: It means your custom view. I have edited the answer now, please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) > 5
        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
    Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
   // do stuff on back key press event
    return true; 
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

same you can use onkeyup override method based on your requirement.

Comment: You doesn't need to add any listener for this event, just override this method in activity